# Make npm ignore folders starting by certain prefix

Tags: npm, gitignore, npmignore

Right now my `.gitignore` files has the following rule:

```
demos/test**
```

Which seems to be working fine with Git (and github) and ignoring the following folders:

```
./demos/test-whatever/
./demos/test/
```

But when publishing to npm, those folders are not ignored and are being published.

Any way to exclude them from npm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a **.npmignore file** in your root directory and add your `demos/test**` ignore rule to this file. For reference:

**.npmignore**

```
   demos/test**
```

Comment: I thought npm would make use of .gitignore when .npmignore was not found?

Comment: This is indeed suppose to happen according to their documentation, but in my experience this has proven otherwise. There is an open issue: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17280 for this but idk if it has received any traction. You can always experiment with your .gitignore file and run npm pack to see what it would publish and check out the result locally. Hopefully that helps, otherwise I would use a .npmignore file

Answer (score 2):

You may want [`.npmignore`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package) to keep files out of your package.

Comment: I thought npm would make use of `.gitignore` when `.npmignore` was not found?

Comment: @Alvaro check my [project demo](https://github.com/FaiChou/ImagePreviewer/blob/master/.npmignore) for usage.

Answer (score 0):

Try a `.npmignore` file [More info](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package)

Comment: I thought npm would make use of .gitignore when .npmignore was not found?